# Differential equation involving functions and value of function at two points are given.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

The equation is $$2 (f(x))^2 - \frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}f(x) + \left(\frac{df(x)}{dx}\right)^2=0   $$

It is also given that $f(0)=f(1)=1$.

I tried to solve by substituting $y$ in place of $f(x)$:
$$2y^2-y''y+(y')^2=0$$ 
 but I could not reduce it to any form that I could solve. Is there some special way to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution of the ODE is (Mathematica):

$$ y(x) = A \exp{(x^2 + B x)},$$

where $A$ and $B$ are integration constants, whose value may be determined from the boundary conditions.

---

**Why?**

Note that your equation may be expressed equivalently as

$$ \frac{y y'' - (y')^2}{y^2} = 2$$

and note that the lhs is equal to $(y'/y)'$. Integrate once to find $y'/y = 2 x + c$ and once more to end up with the solution presented above.

Comment: Oh! @Dmoreno that is an excellent solution.Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Glad to help, @AnanthKamath!